# change value in object array from array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to Change the value in nested array from array in javascript.
I have a `obj` and `arr` in which i need to replace `month` value with arr value in javascript,
i.e for "12" should be "Dec"

```
var arr = ["Jan", "Feb","Mar", "Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
var obj =[{
  "month": "12",
  "year": "2013"
},
{
  "month": "10",
  "year": "2012"
}]
```

Expected Output:

```
[{
  "month": "Dec",
  "year": "2013"
},
{
  "month": "Oct",
  "year": "2012"
}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the desired output:

```js
const months = ["Jan", "Feb","Mar", "Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
const data =[{"month": "12", "year": "2013"}, { "month": "10", "year": "2012"}];

const result = data.map(
  o => ({...o, month: months[o.month - 1]})
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the array of objects, use [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) to copy the original properties of the object, and get the month's name from `arr` using the numeric index (0 based) by subtracting 1 from the month number (1 based):

```js
const arr = ["Jan", "Feb","Mar", "Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
const obj =[{ "month": "12", "year": "2013" }, { "month": "10", "year": "2012" }]

const result = obj.map(o => ({
  ...o, // copy the original properties of the object
  month: arr[o.month - 1], // get the month from arr
}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other answers using a `forEach` loop instead of `map` function

```js
var arr = ["Jan", "Feb","Mar", "Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];

var obj =[{
  "month": "12",
  "year": "2013"
},
{
  "month": "10",
  "year": "2012"
}];


obj.forEach( o=>{
 o.month=arr[ o.month-1 ]
})
console.info( obj )
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
var obj = [{
    "month": "12",
    "year": "2013"
  },
  {
    "month": "10",
    "year": "2012"
  }
]

obj.map(ob => ob.month = arr[ob.month - 1])

console.log(obj)
```

This will mapp over your outer obj array and replace each inner objects month key with the corresponding month from the array

Answer (score -1):

Check out this :-

```js
var obj =[{
  "month": "12",
  "year": "2013"
},
{
  "month": "10",
  "year": "2012"
}]


var result = [];
obj.forEach((obj, i) => {

obj.month=GetMonthName(obj.month);
   
     
     result.push(obj);
     
 });
 
debugger;console.log(result);

function GetMonthName(monthNumber) {
      var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
      return months[monthNumber - 1];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You dont need an array of month names for conversion, you can use `new Date.setMonth()` and `.toLocaleString` to get the same.

```js
var obj =[{
  "month": "12",
  "year": "2013"
},
{
  "month": "10",
  "year": "2012"
}]

let out = obj.map(e => ({...e, month: new Date(new Date().setMonth(e.month - 1)).toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' })}));
console.log(out)
```